# Pyportal Crashes when accessing internet

Tags: python, python-3.x, adafruit-circuitpython

I am trying to build an alarm clock for class, but whenever I run the code and the clock has to connect to the internet, the clock crashes. How would I fix this? Is it a problem with the Pyportal or with the code?

**Edit: it also crashes when running a wifi test found here - https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_PyPortal/blob/master/examples/pyportal_simpletest.py

By crash, I mean the Pyportal will turn off, turn back on, and run in safe mode. **

The code in the part when it will crash is

```
# Set up where we'll be fetching data from
DATA_SOURCE = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/w'
DATA_SOURCE += 'eather?id='+secrets['city_id']
DATA_SOURCE += '&appid='+secrets['API_TOKEN']
# You'll need to get a token from openweather.org,
# looks like 'b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22'
DATA_LOCATION = []

####################
# setup hardware

pyportal = PyPortal(url=DATA_SOURCE,
                    json_path=DATA_LOCATION,
                    status_neopixel=board.NEOPIXEL)
```

Comment: Hi there, what do u mean crash? can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: @Cryptoharf84 by crash, I mean starts running in safe mode

Comment: stick a print(DATA_SOURCE) right after pyportal =. Copy and paste the value of DATA_SOURCE into a browser. What are the results? Any indication of a bad url?